# script to rename a file with appending timestamp to the file and add md5 checksum to the end of the file

Tags: unix

I want to rename filename with appending timestamp to it and add a md5 checksum at the end of the file. For I have file abc123.txt. I want to rename as abc. Also at the end of the file as a footer add md5 checksum count.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. The commands `(cat abc123.txt; md5sum < abc123.txt) > abc && rm abc123.txt` might fulfill the (incomplete) requirements in your question, but I guess that's not what you are looking for.

Comment: To be more precise. Say i have a file abc.txt with 10 records in it including header. I want to append the below in 11th line of the file.

Comment: To be more precise. Say i have a file abc.txt with 10 records in it including header. I want to rename the file as abc_<yyyymmdd>.txt and in the 11th line of the file, I want to append - <checksum_value>and in the 12th line <tot number of records>.